# Tomcat8 HTTP Status 500 - Servlet execution threw an exception

Tags: java, http, tomcat

I have tried to use method in other package in a site.
Firstly, I imported the class of the package and run the project as java application successfully.
However, when I run the project on server it seems to have problems.

Here is my java code
[run as java application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuYCL.png)

[the original class being called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFjJ1.png)

[the site having problems running as server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ne1Ir.png)

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import print.print;

@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")

public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


public String getTranslation(String test) {
    return print.getTest(test);
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String originalText = "Hello";
    System.out.println(getTranslation(originalText));
}
```

`}`

[the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T16w.png)

Comment: Don't paste code as images. Read [ask].

Comment: The `*` in your images for `HelloServlet.java` means that this code is not saved.

Comment: The error means that it can not find that class - have you corectly deployed it to your server?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I have built path between the two projects. Is that means the class deployed to the server?

Comment: The jar file (or class) should be included somewhere below your `webapps/<project>/WEB-INF`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I run it successfully under your guidance! Thank you very much! You are so kind :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because I only build a path between two projects instead of compressing the "print" project into JAR file.

Thanks a lot for viewing the problem!